# Using regex or string manipulation when creating permalinks

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have following method(and looks expensive too) for creating permalinks but it's lacking few stuff that are quite important for nice permalink:

```
   public string createPermalink(string text)
        {
            text = text.ToLower().TrimStart().TrimEnd();

            foreach (char c in text.ToCharArray())
            {
                if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) && !char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
                {

                   text = text.Replace(c.ToString(), "");
                }

                if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
                {
                    text = text.Replace(c, '-');
                }
            }

            if (text.Length > 200)
            {
                text = text.Remove(200);
            }

            return text;
        }
```

Few stuff that it is lacking:

if someone enters text like this: 
`"My choiches are:foo,bar"` would get returned as `"my-choices-arefoobar"`
and it should be like: `"my-choiches-are-foo-bar"`

and If someone enters multiple white spaces it would get returned as "---" which is not nice to have in url.

Is there some better way to do this in regex(I really only used it few times)?

---

UPDATE:

Requirement was:

- Any non digit or letter chars at beginning or end are not allowed
- Any non digit or letter chars should be replaced by "-"
- When replaced with "-" chars should not reapeat like "---"
- And finally stripping string at index 200 to ensure it's not too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to

```
public string createPermalink(string text)
{
    text = text.ToLower();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text.Length);

    // We want to skip the first hyphenable characters and go to the "meat" of the string
    bool lastHyphen = true;

    // You can enumerate directly a string
    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
        {
            sb.Append(c);
            lastHyphen = false;
        }       
        else if (!lastHyphen)
        {
            // We use lastHyphen to not put two hyphens consecutively
            sb.Append('-');
            lastHyphen = true;
        }

        if (sb.Length == 200)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Remove the last hyphen
    if (sb.Length > 0 && sb[sb.Length - 1] == '-')
    {
        sb.Length--;
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

If you really want to use regexes, you can do something like this (based on the code of Justin)

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^\W+|\W+$");    
Regex rgx2 = new Regex(@"\W+"); 
return rgx2.Replace(rgx.Replace(text.ToLower(), string.Empty), "-");
```

The first regex searches for non-word characters (1 or more) at the beginning (`^`) or at the end of the string (`$`) and removes them. The second one replaces one or more non-word characters with `-`.

Comment: That is it, only thing that is missing is if first char is sign it would start with "-" but I can add check for that myself.

Comment: Corrected... Now it does check.

Comment: I finally decided to use your regex,seems less error prone than anything else and works like I could never expected 3 lines of code could :) Thanks xanatos and Justin

Comment: Yes, I just realized that one regex will leave the invalid characters, so for that reason, you will need the two

Answer (score 1):

This should solve the problem that you have explained. Please let me know if it needs any further explanation.
Just as an FYI, the regex makes use of [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to get it done in one run

```
//This will find any non-character word, lumping them in one group if more than 1
//It will ignore non-character words at the beginning or end of the string
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?!\W+$)\W+(?<!^\W+)");
//This will then replace those matches with a -
string result = rgx.Replace(input, "-");
```

To keep the string from going beyond 200 characters, you will have to use [substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx). If you do this before the regex, then you will be ok, but if you do it after, then you run the risk of having a trailing dash again, FYI.

example:

```
myString.Substring(0,200)
```

Comment: problem is also if string ends with sign like "hello!" would get translated to "hello-" which is not good for url to end with.

Comment: Updated my code to deal with the final -. Please make sure to update your question to reflect this new requirement, though

Comment: Re-updated my code to deal with your new requirements. I was able to make this into one regex :)

Answer (score 0):

I use an iterative approach for this - because in some cases you might want certain characters to be turned into words instead of having them turned into '-' characters - e.g. '&' -> 'and'.

But when you're done you'll also end up with a string that potentially contains multiple '-' - so you have a final regex that collapses all multiple '-' characters into one.

So I would suggest using an ordered list of regexes, and then run them all in order.  This code is written to go in a static class that is then exposed as a single extension method for `System.String` - and is probably best merged into the `System` namespace.

I've hacked it from code I use, which had extensibility points (e.g. you could pass in a `MatchEvaluator` on construction of the replacement object for more intelligent replacements; and you could pass in your own IEnumerable of replacements, as the class was public), and therefore it might seem unnecessarily complicated - judging by the other answers I'm guessing everybody will think so (but I have specific requirements for the SEO of the strings that are created).

The list of replacements I use might not be exactly correct for your uses - if not, you can just add more.

```
private class SEOSymbolReplacement
{
   private Regex _rx;
   private string _replacementString;

   public SEOSymbolReplacement(Regex r, string replacement)
   {
     //null-checks required.
     _rx = r;
     _replacementString = replacement;
   }

   public string Execute(string input)
   {
     /null-check required
     return _rx.Replace(input, _replacementString);
   }
}

private static readonly SEOSymbolReplacement[] Replacements = { 
  new SEOSymbolReplacement(new Regex(@"#", RegexOptions.Compiled), "Sharp"),
  new SEOSymbolReplacement(new Regex(@"\+", RegexOptions.Compiled), "Plus"),
  new SEOSymbolReplacement(new Regex(@"&", RegexOptions.Compiled), " And "),
  new SEOSymbolReplacement(new Regex(@"[|:'\\/,_]", RegexOptions.Compiled), "-"),
  new SEOSymbolReplacement(new Regex(@"\s+", RegexOptions.Compiled), "-"),
  new SEOSymbolReplacement(new Regex(@"[^\p{L}\d-]", 
                           RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled), ""),
  new SEOSymbolReplacement(new Regex(@"-{2,}", RegexOptions.Compiled), "-")};


/// <summary>
/// Transforms the string into an SEO-friendly string.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="str"></param>
public static string ToSEOPathString(this string str)
{
    if (str == null)
        return null;
    string toReturn = str;
    foreach (var replacement in DefaultReplacements)
    {
        toReturn = replacement.Execute(toReturn);
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: That is nice altought I think that translation for "#" would better be "numbers" instead of "sharp" at least in app where you don't expect people writing something like "C#".

Comment: yes you're right.  We use it as `"Sharp"` particularly because the likelihood is the original phrase is `"C#"` or `"F#"`